# Understanding of Histogram-of-Oriented-Gradients

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, object-detection, feature-extraction

I am learning about HOG and I understand it from [here](https://www.learnopencv.com/histogram-of-oriented-gradients/). A well-explained page with an example. I am not understanding this concept that how it works

> A 16×16 block has 4 histograms which can be concatenated to form a 36
>   x 1 element vector and it can be normalized just the way a 3×1 vector
>   is normalized.

How this **36*1** came and how we calculated it? and is it compulsory that we always need 9 bin vector? Is it a fixed size for HOG?

came?

Comment: 8x8 block creates a 9-bin histogram. A 16x16 block = 4 blocks of 8x8 so it has 4 histograms and can be concatenated to form a 36 x 1 (9x4). And I'm not sure that 9 bin vector is a must or not, but it's recommended.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it compulsory that we always need 9 bin vector?

Not necessarily. Dalal and Triggs stated in [their original HOG paper](https://lear.inrialpes.fr/people/triggs/pubs/Dalal-cvpr05.pdf) that accuracy for their application (which was human pedestrian detection) increased when using up to 9 bins, after that the accuracy did not increase any further, that's why 9 are commonly used.

> How this 36*1 came and how we calculated it?

As already pointed out in the comments:

You have **9 bins per histogram** (which will each be a scalar value in your feature vector). In your example, a histogram was calculated using **8 x 8** blocks, meaning in a **16 x 16** block you will be able to calculate **4 histograms**. Each of those histograms will yield a **9 x 1** feature vector so:

**4** (histograms) * **9** (bins) = **36 x 1** feature vector.

You basically just concatenate your results into one vector.